# Get a hold on a nested span

Tags: html, css, drupal, drupal-theming

How can I get a hold on the `h2 span` element?

[image]

`div#content div.view-content div.view-row-item h2 span { ...` is not working...

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use span.field-content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using FireBug, you can right-click the span tag and 'copy css path' and that will give you the complete path to the element starting from 'html'

Answer (score 2):

You're missing an `s` in `div.view-row-item`, it should be:

```
div#content div.view-content div.views-row-item h2 span {
```

Comment: Of course... a stupid typo. But still no result. You should think I specify enough no? What is the deepest level I can specify?

Comment: Personally I'd just use `#content h2 span.field-content`, it's a shorter rule and definitely targets the elements you're after. I'm not sure what the deepest level you can specify is (or if there's even a limit), but it'll be a very large number. According to [this experiment](http://helephant.com/2007/08/04/extreme-nesting-experiment-in-ie-and-firefox/): IE will stop rendering at the 28th level of table and Firefox will stop at the 34th

Answer (score 2):

In your example you've missed an 's' you need:

```
div#content div.view-content div.views-row-item h2 span
```

viewS-row-item